# Can minors apply for a visa on their own to travel to South Korea for a K-Pop training program?

Tags: visas, air-travel, minors, scams

Does a minor need their parents' permission to apply for a visa and to travel unaccompanied to another country?

I am a 15-year-old Tunisian and want to attend a K-Pop training program in South Korea.

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions in one. Please don't do that. I suggest you [edit] your question and leave only the parts about minors. The trainee contracts can be a separate question, but if you do that, give it some more information. It is unclear what you are asking there exactly (I  know, language barrier)

Comment: Sorry , ok the first part is about minors making their visa alone . Is it ok if they do that and if so what are the requirments ?

Comment: I love your question. Tell us this: do you have a contract with a company to be trained for K-Pop and, if yes, what country it is in?

Comment: The second part is about being a trainee to become artist .. The company will maybe send you a contract when you print it can it justify your visa because I'm not sure if you go trainning it's considered as a studing visa

Comment: Dorothy I still don't know if I'm accepted but I'm sure if so I'll get one and it's in South Korea

Comment: Rahma and where are you (or described minors) from?

Comment: @Kuba i'm from Tunisia

Comment: If it is a [program such as this one](http://www.fncgtc.com/main/main.php),  you would need a student or visitor visa. The contract is for you to pay the program for the training.

Comment: @Dorothy Accually the company will pay me , will find me a dorm to live in . Student visa ( from internet ) lasts 2 years but what if I'm going to get the nationality because I'm going to grow , become an adult while working .

Comment: Then, with such an arrangement, they will help with the visa. The issue will be your age now, and what has to be done legally to protect you. You and your family will want to consult with an attorney.

Comment: @Dorothy I'm fifteen my parents won't make it to the  Municipal so I'm wondering if I can go alone and bring all the papers i should present and get the visa done .

Comment: You probably won't have much luck trying to do this on your own. A quick check says that, in Tunisia, you have to be 18. Perhaps you could convince your parents to let you attend a one-month program first, traveling there with a family member, or to let you do a shorter student exchange program.

Comment: I'd double check to make sure you aren't being scammed.  The offer sounds too good to be true.

Comment: @JonathanReez Finding us a dorm I'm not 100per sure about it while being a trainee but while starting the career and being an idol , yes of course .

Comment: @Dorothy my parents can't even go to the municipal , my friends could travel alone on plane but the main problem is going alone to the municipal and applying for visa . Is it ok if they write a lettre and sign and I give it with the other papers ?

Comment: This sets off all kind of alarm bells. A minor girl, setting out to travel internationally across half a planet for a nebulous much-too-good-to-be-true job offer -- and apparently being encouraged to make arrangements without her parents' knowledge? I smell not just a scam but trafficking. Seriously, run! Or **at the very least** get an adult you know and trust to help unravel things for you -- not random people on the internet.

Comment: @HenningMakholm These Korean companies receive people even forgeiner through online audition once axepted as trainees they train during a specific amount of time,  they decide , once they are ready they become idols or anything else artistic as groups or solos and then they find them a manager and a dorm and they live in the dorm with the manager , and they got payed . You can check these companies like sm entertaiment / yg entertaiment / jyp entertaiment . But I don't know what to do exactly !

Comment: You're 15, and those of us who are connecting with you here are very concerned for your well being. It sounds like your parents are, too, and are not in favor of you going off to Korea for two years, on your own. If your dream is to be a performer, try to find a program that your parents will let you attend, one that is closer to home,

Comment: @Dorothy thanks for your support but it's a dream , after it I wn't ask for anything . I 'm responsible enough to make a visa , fly alone and take care of myself I'm already collecting money in case , . So how bad could it be?  ; a minor going to the municipal to get a visa and then remake it in Korea , become an adult and get the nationality .

Comment: @Rahma: "How bad could it be?" Instead of on a stage, you could end up enslaved in a brothel, with no money, no papers, no contacts, in a society whose language you don't speak even if your manage to escape -- that's how bad. And based on what you're saying, the latter sounds like a more likely outcome. Korea doesn't hand out citizenships to people just for being present in the country when they turn 18. You may have a dream, but you're being lied to by people who claim they can make it come true.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you ,  that sounds real and responsible but  I only made this hard decision  after a lot of wise thinking and consequences highlighting ! All what I'm asking now is how to get things done and I'm actually 16 I need to see life and  deal with problems  .

Comment: Find an adult you trust in real-life (not on the Internet) and get advice from them. The worst-case scenario is awful. "Advertisements **look like legitimate jobs**, but women are required to engage in sex service once they are hired. ... brothels abuse them economically, physically, and mentally."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_trafficking_in_South_Korea#Sex_trafficking

Comment: @RahmaAzzouz You may have done a lot of thinking but it's not wise thinking.  You're just trying to convince yourself it's real when the chance of it being real is mighty close to zero.  The only thing they're going to teach you is how to be a properly subservient whore.

Comment: Thanks everyone I'll maybe wait until becoming adult and more mature ! I'll focus on my studies now and get a honorable job .

Answer (score 6):

The official visa page of the South Korean embassy in Tunisia [doesn't mention such a restriction](http://tun.mofa.go.kr/worldlanguage/africa/tun/visa/issuance/index.jsp), however it's likely that they will ask you for a signed permission from your parents as it's standard policy of most consulates worldwide.

Regardless of the visa requirements, you should be **extremely** careful about offers from abroad that sound too good to be true. There are hundreds of thousands of teenagers in South Korea itself who would love to enter a "K-Pop training program", so I'd be very suspicious if someone invited an underage person for a "chance to become an idol". If you do plan to go, please double check with your parents and then double check with the Korean consulate if the program is actually legitimate. You do not want to end up in South Korea as a victim of human trafficking, so please apply **serious scrutiny** before you leave.

Answer (score 3):

> Does a minor need a parents permission to apply for a visa and to travel unaccompanied to another country?

Absolutely. Example for [Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/minors.asp)

> If a minor child is travelling alone
>
> The child should present:
>
> a letter of authorization, in English or French if possible, and signed by both parents or by their legal guardian which lists:
> the parents’ (or legal guardian’s) address and telephone number, and
> the name, address and telephone number of the adult who will look after the child in Canada.

[United Kingdom](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18)

> You can travel to the UK without an adult (someone over the age of 18).
>
> Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:
>
> written consent for you to travel to the UK

South Africa a Parental Consent Affidavit is required, here is a [Sample](http://www.dha.gov.za/files/ParentalConsentAffidavit.pdf). And so forth.

Most airlines won't accept a minor child (although the age for that varies) without parental consent either.

Comment: Thank you so much . I'm fifteen my parents won't make it to go Municipal so I'm wondering if I can go alone and bring all the papers i should present . And what are the requirements For South-Korea ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your passport already?  The majority of countries require a parents signature for a minor to apply for the passport.  And showing up without them, with an already signed application, will likely be refused as there is no way to prove your parents actually signed the document.

Can you apply for a visa without your parents?  You need to call the South Korea Embassy to find out their rules on issuing visas to minors. Each country's regulations vary and those rules can even vary from consular location to consular location (ie rules for Korean visas issued in the UK can be different than rules for Tunisia).

Can you leave the country and fly without your parents?  You need to confirm rules with the airline you plan to fly on out of Tunisia what their rules are for boarding minors on international flights.  You also need to confirm with the South Korean Embassy what rules apply to you when you actually enter the country (assuming they issue a visa).  It is highly likely you will need at a minimum a notarized letter from your parents authorizing you to travel without them (which means your parents WILL need to go to the municipal offices or other offices authorized to notarize / certify a signature).

But one has to ask, since your parents seem unwilling to help you with your procedures, do you actually have their permission to do this?

Comment: Tom I have a passeport . I want to finish the work without my parents help , going to to the municipal making the visa and getting tickets . And yes let's say that they're ok but really can't go to the municipal .